# add entry to TOC table of contents only in pdf structure using hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, hyperref, pdf

I want to add an item to the pdf structure that is generated using `hyperref`, but *not* add it to the TOC that is printed visually using `\tableofcontents`.

When using `\addtocontents` or  for example `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur}` it will be added to *both* the TOC within the document and the pdf structure. I only want to acheive the latter.

Picture: [Here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pdf%20table%20of%20contents&t=lm&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.softany.com%2Fchm-to-pdf%2Fimages%2Ftoc.png) it can be seen the TOC in pdf structure on the left panel and the visual TOC in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There is `\pdfbookmark` but the exact answer to your question might depend on the desired result. You might want to add some background.

Comment: There is also the [`bookmark`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookmark/bookmark.pdf) package that provides flexible options for adding pdf bookmarks.

Comment: Or use the bookmark package, it has lots of support for this.

Comment: Thanks, that made it work well ! After knowing this package it is easy to find, but without the knowledge that it exists, it was difficult to search for it and my search yielded no results.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by a package recommendation in comments.